# How do you use reqGetParams (Yesod) properly?

Tags: haskell, yesod

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell, QuasiQuotes, OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, TypeFamilies #-}

import Yesod
import Control.Monad (void)

data Foo = Foo

mkYesod "Foo" [parseRoutes|
    / FooR POST
|]

instance Yesod Foo

-- Always prints "".
postFooR = void $
    getRequest >>= liftIO . print . ("Params :" ++) . concatMap show . reqGetParams

main = warp 3000 Foo
```

I'm working my way through a couple Yesod tutorials, but I'm stuck on trying to inspect POST parameters. Here's what happens when I run the above code:

```
$ runhaskell foo.hs
$ curl --data "foo=bar" localhost:3000

14/Jul/2013:15:01:51 -0700 [Info#yesod-core] Application launched @(yesod-core-1.2.3:Yesod.Core.Dispatch ./Yesod/Core/Dispatch.hs:129:11)
"Params: "
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Jul/2013:15:02:07 -0700] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 - "" "curl/7.30.0"
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: `curl --data` will send params via POST, while `reqGetParams` will give you params that were passed in the URL; ie "localhost:3000?foo=bar". I'm not familiar enough with Yesod to tell you how to access the POST data though.

Answer (score 1):

I think the function you're looking for is [`runRequestBody`](http://haddocks.fpcomplete.com/fp/7.4.2/20130622-109/yesod-core/Yesod-Core-Handler.html#v%3arunRequestBody).